# Why does WhatsApp keep crashing?

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger

I've received a new phone (A53), and for the past week, for both the old (S10) and new phones WhatsApp keep crashing.

When opening WhatsApp, there's usually a black screen (or white, it probably depends if you're on dark mode); if it doesn't crash, when scrolling in chats/entering a chat it freezes and I receive a "whatsapp is not responding" text.
Even sending texts are broken, for if I choose to send, it's not being sent, and the message disappears..

Re-installation doesn't fix it.

My wifi/data are okay, I cleaned the cashe, and I have about 9 GB worth of data in WhatsApp.

What can be a fix for that? I'd love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Based on my experience with the same issue, it's possibly caused by database corruption. I don't really have a solution because my device was also dying at that time, other than clearing all the chat/data of WhatsApp.